# What are these lines of batch code for?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I came across the following batch code on SuperUser, the purpose of which is to programmatically replace a folder's icon.

```
CD "%userprofile%\desktop"
MKDIR "TEST FOLDER"
ATTRIB +s "TEST FOLDER"
CD "TEST FOLDER"
COPY /Y "%userprofile%\desktop\image.ico" "./image.ico"
ECHO [.ShellClassInfo] >> desktop.txt
ECHO ConfirmFileOp=0 >> desktop.txt
ECHO NoSharing=1 >> desktop.txt
ECHO IconFile=image.ico >> desktop.txt
ECHO IconIndex=0 >> desktop.txt
ECHO InfoTip= >> desktop.txt
CHCP 1252 >NUL
CMD.EXE /D /A /C (SET/P=ÿþ)<NUL > desktop.ini 2>NUL
CMD.EXE /D /U /C TYPE desktop.txt >> desktop.ini
DEL /F /Q desktop.txt
ATTRIB +S +H desktop.ini image.ico
```

I get the rest of the script easily enough, but I'm having trouble understanding these three lines:

```
CHCP 1252 >NUL
CMD.EXE /D /A /C (SET/P=ÿþ)<NUL > desktop.ini 2>NUL
CMD.EXE /D /U /C TYPE desktop.txt >> desktop.ini
```

SS64 tells me `chcp 1252` is related to something called a ["code page"](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html), 1252 corresponding to "West European Latin", so my best guess is that this forces the script to use a Latin character set. The second two lines open instances of CMD; [SS64](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) says the /A switch on the first makes it output in ANSI while the /U on the second makes it output Unicode. That's about as much as I can speculate on, and I'd really appreciate it if someone could go through each major part of these three lines and tell me what they're doing.

Thanks!

Comment: chcp changes the codepage of your keyboard: [read more](http://www.computerhope.com/chcphlp.htm) and  the cmd lines manipulate your desktop.ini

Comment: @mtizziani: Code pages and keyboards are completely unrelated. `CHCP` changes the interpretation of data from STDIN and the output to STDOUT of the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, the code<sup>[1]</sup>
:

- creates a *temporary* `desktop.txt` file whose *content* will eventually become `desktop.ini`, but with a *different encoding*.
- the commands in question then convert the current-console-codepage-encoded file `desktop.txt` (e.g., on an en-US system, `CP-437`) to `UTF-16 LE`-encoded file `desktop.ini`, which is the (culture-independent) file File Explorer uses to control display of the folder at hand.
- sets the `system` (`+S`) and `hidden` (`+H`) attributes for both the `desktop.ini` file and the associated icon file, `image.ico`, because that's how these files should be marked (given that they only control *display* of the containing folder, and aren't data files themselves).

Specifically, the 3 lines of interest do the following:

- `CHCP 1252 >NUL` (silently) changes to the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) code page.
- `CMD.EXE /D /A /C (SET/P=ÿþ)<NUL > desktop.ini 2>NUL` effectively sends string `ÿþ` to output file `desktop.ini` - `ÿþ`, when interpreted as a `Windows-1252`-encoded string, amounts to bytes `0xFF 0xFE`, which is the BOM (byte-order mark) used to identify `UTF-16 LE`-encoded files; in other words: sending this string to file `desktop.ini` marks it as an `UTF-16 LE`-encoded file.

  - `/D` simply suppresses any auto-run functionality that may be defined via the registry
  - `/A` tells `cmd.exe` to output "ANSI"-encoded strings, where "ANSI" refers to the default codepage - which is now set to `Windows-1252`
  - `/C` means that the following arguments should be executed as a command, and that `cmd.exe` should exit after the command terminates.
- `CMD.EXE /D /U /C TYPE desktop.txt >> desktop.ini` then *appends* the contents of the previously created `desktop.txt` file to `desktop.ini`, using "Unicode" (`UTF-16 LE`) encoding (thanks to `/U`), which completes the conversion of temporary file `desktop.txt` to `UTF-16 LE`-encoded `desktop.ini` (after which `desktop.txt` is removed).

---

[1]
This answer interprets the code's *intent*, which doesn't mean that it  necessarily *works*, especially in Windows 10; for instance, interactively assigning an icon seems to set a different, *single* property that *combines* the image file and the index of its specific internal resource: e.g., `IconResource=C:\Users\jdoe\Desktop\image.ico,0`

As for the need to create `UTF-16 LE`-encoded files: it's not a strict requirement - apparently, Windows itself, when you use File Explorer to assign an icon, creates files in the current *legacy* - single-byte - encoding (e.g., `Windows-1252`).
That said, using a *culture-independent* encoding such as `UTF-16 LE` is at least in principle the most robust approach.
However, if all the values you're writing to `desktop.ini` are ASCII-only characters (7-bit range), it's safe to simply pipe `echo` output to `desktop.ini` directly.

At the end of the day, using a *batch file* to determine folder display attributes is a *fragile* approach, given that it is essentially based on reverse-engineering the official APIs - which may change.

More generally, using batch files to do *anything* is best avoided these days - use PowerShell instead.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. Is there a purpose to all the messing around with  creating a temporary text file first, and then converting that to `UTF-16` encoding? It seems really convoluted. Can any of it be simplified? Does the .ini need to be encoded in `UTF-16` at all - could you not create the file directly and just add the `system` and `hidden` attributes?

Comment: @Hashim: Please see my update. I'm afraid I'm giving up on going further down this rabbit hole...

Comment: Haha, that's more than fair enough, it's a very thorough answer. I still have more questions, and probably more after those get answered - this seems to be one of those fields where each answer brings up 2 more questions for me, probably not helped by a lack of grounding in the big picture, making it far too easy to get lost down rabbit holes of questions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hashim: Thanks; glad you found it useful. The batch language of the Windows command processor (`cmd.exe`), has always been severely limited, and has evolved very little over the years.
People have cleverly stretched it to its limits in the past to get things done anyway, but with the advent of PowerShell there is no longer a reasons to struggle.
PowerShell is not only a powerful shell, but unique among shells in its ability to make system calls via the .NET framework, which means there's little
you _cannot_ do in PowerShell (although performance may be a concern).

Comment: Does PowerShell allow you able to create executable .bat files or equivalent like batch scripting does?

Comment: @Hashim: Once you enable execution of scripts with [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812(v=wps.650).aspx), you can run your script files (`*.ps1`), both from within PowerShell and externally via `powershell -noprofile -file <script>.ps1`.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Based on what you say and what I've read, there's more configuration involved to get PowerShell scripts to execute on a user's machine than there are with batch files, which are essentially the scripting equivalent of plug-and-play. The portability is essential. It's the reason batch files are still the go-to solution for things like hotfixes and extensibility of Windows - and the reason I'm writing the short script I'm currently working on in batch; to make it useful to as many users as possible without them needing to configure anything beforehand.

Comment: @Hashim: I get it: security is _inconvenient_:  there's an inherent, unresolvable tension between convenience and security.
It is nice to be able to just run any batch file, but it's also _dangerous_.
In enterprises, group policy and signed scripts can jump the PowerShell hurdle; otherwise, you'll just have to ask users to run something like
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned` in a PowerShell console before they can run your scripts.

Comment: It's dangerous for users, yes, and therefore a good general rule, which is why I understand the reasoning behind the PowerShell limitations. But when you're writing the script itself, and you know what it will do, there's no danger involved and it's pure inconvenience. If I'm writing a batch script for my grandma, I know what's in it and that it's safe for her to run, and I want her to be able to do so without pre-configuration from someone more computer-savvy; hence, the usefulness of batch, which I don't think will go away any time soon.

Comment: @Hashim: If it's your grandma, remote into her machine _once_, or walk up  to her machine _once_, and configure PowerShell so that it'll run your scripts in the future.